# How's Yeoman's AngularJS generator referencing Bootstrap SASS files?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman

I generated a new AngularJS app using Yeoman:

```
yo angular
```

And selected the SASS-based Bootstrap files to be included as well.

Now `index.html` has a block of code that looks like this:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/plugins.js -->
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/affix.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/alert.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/button.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/transition.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/modal.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/tab.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/popover.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

But my app's `app/bower_components` folder does not have `sass-bootstrap`. Where are these `sass-bootstrap` files located at?

Comment: have you run bower install yet?  Not sure if this is supposed to be built into yeoman's process or not but bower install should install any dependendencies from the bower.json file

Comment: When you ran yeoman, where there any errors in the output? Like @shaunhusain said, you probably just need to run `bower install` from the root of your project

Answer (score 4):

you have to run "bower install sass-bootstrap -save" from the command line in your project's root directory to install it.   sass-bootstrap  isn't being put in bower.json, which is why you have to install it and then add the -save so it puts the entry in bower.json.